# From php web to wordpress conversion, href changes only in URL

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, html5

I have converted my PHP dynamic website into WordPress. Whole design is perfect. But unfortunately, when I click on any href link. it just changes in URL but not displaying the related linked page. Following images clarify more good:

[image: index.php page]

**When Clicking on link addDegree.php From sidebar nav:**

```
<li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Degree Pages">
          <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDegreePages" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
            <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" style="color:gray;"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Degree Management</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseDegreePages">
            <li>
              <a href="addDegree.php">Add New Degree</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="viewDegrees.php">View All Degrees</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

**As in image:**

[image]

**See URL in below image:**

[image]

***Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks!***

Comment: Did you actually convert everything to WP, as in custom post types etc.? It looks like you are linking to an "addDegree.php" file which is not actually the WP way. Normally you would create a plugin and the plugin would be used to add CPTs and Taxonomies for these various buttons you have showing.

Comment: No, I have just copy my php web to wordpress themes folder, my style.css file was not working before but then i used bloginfo function with template_directory paramater in style link hrefant it was done...i haso applied the same function for a href but it still not working..

Comment: Elaine seems to be onto the problem.  Recommend creating a theme and plugins in WP then carrying your content over for each page.  More work but then you are truly able to use the core features of WP.

Comment: @jdm2112 you mean I have to create addNewDegree.php page using CPT to work the href links properly. same process for all my cutom pages of php web..RIGHT?

Comment: No, you will create a "degree" CPT. WordPress will automatically add a link in the left admin navigation to create degrees. You will have to do some work to learn the concepts of WP but once you do you'll find its Core behavior will save a lot of the work you have been doing manually.

Comment: can you have a refrence or link for this?